# Rails, DEVISE - Preventing a user from changing their email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

When a user registers on my app they have to confirm their email, powered by Devise + Rails 3.

The email address defines the user's permissions so I don't want the user to be able to change it once registered. so removed :email from the users.rb attr_accessible which worked for a logged in user, but now user's can't register.

What's the right way to handle this? So users can't update their email but can register with their email using devise.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is the perfect case for a custom validator. Since Rails3, they are much easier to do than before.

```
class ImmutableValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    record.errors[attribute] << "cannot be changed after creation" if record.send("#{attribute}_changed?") && !record.new_record?
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, :immutable => true
end
```

Comment: Thanks, is that plugin Rails 3 friendly? It doesn't look to have been touched in years. I really like your custom validator idea, seems clean and simple. How do you check for new_record? Mind showing how to do this? thanks

Comment: @AnApprentice You're right, can't vouch for Rails3 compatibility. Custom validators are much easier than they used to be, anyway.

Comment: @AnApprentice forgot the dirty attribute check. Should work now.

Comment: Isnt "validates :email, :on => :update, :immutable => true" better than new_record check inside the custom validator? It makes the code more readable.

Comment: @acidburn2k the `:on => :update` setting is implicit in the fact that it's immutable, so it doesn't make any sense to require the user to provide it. I will gladly trade a slightly more ugly implementation for a better API, because implementations are easier to change.

Answer (score 2):

attr_readonly :email

That solved the problem easily.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/plataformatec-devise/skCarCHr0p8

Answer (score 0):

I would personally leave the attr_accessible for :email and just remove the email field from the edit view. Also, you will want to strip out any email param from the params hash in the update action.

Comment: That sounds really dangerous.

Comment: Not recommended. If you forget to screen out the email field once, you have a potential bug or exploit.

Comment: Yea, it was just one approach considering he wasn't going to have the email field anywhere else.

Comment: Definitely not a good idea since removing from the form will not prevent your controller from accept it (using curl, for instance). The best option is probably use [`StrongParameters`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) to avoid the controller from accepting it.