# Devise - Prevent email update attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rails, DEVISE - Preventing a user from changing their email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190578/rails-devise-preventing-a-user-from-changing-their-email-address)

How do I go about preventing the user from updating their email field?  I have a pretty generic devise setup.  I was thinking maybe I could do a general validation check on update in the model.  But perhaps there is a better way to do this.

```
  validate :prevent_email_change, :on => :update
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked much with devise so I can't say for sure if there's a built in way to do this, but normally you use Rails' methods for protecting specific attributes. The safest way to do this is with [attr_accessible](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible), but you can also use attr_protected if you don't anticipate that your model's attributes will change.

In your case, your User model would include the line:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :blah, :blah, :blah
end
```

Note that :email is not listed here since you do not want it to be accessible.

Comment: Well I could do it that way.  But then I wouldn't be able to use mass assignment when the record is created.  This would then require me to write a custom controller for devise and manually assign it in the controller, right?

Comment: I wasn't aware that you didn't already have a controller for managing devise users, so yes you would need to tap into that somehow to manually assign it. Not sure if this would be easier or better than the model validation you suggested, so I would probably explore both ways.